# Why jquery $.get function doesn't call java servlet?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlet-3.0

I want to call this servlet with ajax in jquery:

```
@WebServlet("/getCoursesForSubject")
public class GetCoursesForSubjectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public GetCoursesForSubjectServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
...........
```

And in jsp page I have this jquery code to call ajax request:

```
$("#subjectSelect").change(function(){
        var name = $("#subjectSelect option:selected").text();
        alert("change handler is called "+name);
        $.get("/getCoursesForSubject",{"subjectName":name},function(responseJson){
            $.each(responseJson,function(index,course){
                alert(course);
                $("<option>").appendTo($("#courseSelect")).text(course.courseDescriptionName);
            });
        });
    });
```

The `change` method is called and alert is dsplayed correctly:

```
alert("change handler is called "+name);
```

But next I expect java servlet on path `/getCoursesForSubject` to be invoked but it isn't.

In google chrome's console I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/getCoursesForSubject?subjectName=AS%20-%20Aerospace%20Studies%22 404 ()
```

This means that ajax call was made but server returned 404 error.

It is **solved** by giving `contextPath` to url. Correct `$.get` method is:

```
$.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getCoursesForSubject",{"subjectName":name},function(responseJson){
            $.each(responseJson,function(index,course){
                alert(course);
                $("<option>").appendTo($("#courseSelect")).text(course.courseDescriptionName);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you able to access this URL directly in browser address bar?

Comment: I believe you're sending a post request (since u're posting data) no?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
request.getServletContext()
```

if you are not using JSTL.

With `$.get()` method, make sure servlet has `get` method.

With `$.post()` servlet should contain `post` method.